# WordPress admin page is not showing

Tags: wordpress

My WordPress admin page is not showing.
I have attached the screenshot for the error.
I have rewrite my .htaccess file too. Now my .htaccess file contains the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But still I don't know why this error is showing:

[image]

Comment: rename the current .htaccess to .xyz file and refresh on the browser it will create the new .htaccess . this may resolve your issue.

Comment: try replacing the .htaccess with default .htaccess https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

Comment: it is not working @charan kumar

Comment: did you placed correct url under wp_options in database

Comment: yes.. actually the website is working properly in live. but wp-admin page is not opeing..

Comment: which hosting space you are using? and the wp-admin is working in local?

Comment: we are using Godaddy for hosting and it is not working in local too

Answer (score 0):

This is what I had to do for my Wordpress sites on my server. This should go inside your `<VirtualHost *:80>` tags.

```
<Directory /var/www/site>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: where I have to add these lines?

Comment: According to the screenshot you are using Apache. For my install the virtualhost files are located in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ and are '.conf' files. each of these files should begin with <VirtualHost *:80>. These are your Virtual Host files. anywhere after <VirtualHost *:80> and before </VirtualHost> you can paste those (replacing site with the name of the directory your site is in.

This is all assuming that you are in direct control of the host environment.